# Firebase value event listener not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, I have an id that is supposed to be pulled down from firebase real time database. If I pull it down and it sees there is not an id available, then it sets the id to 1. I did a debug, and the id is set to 1, but after the listener finishes, the id goes to 0. I don't know why or what is causing this, but here is my code.

Code for listener:

```
userRef.child("id").

addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        try {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            id = Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            id = 1;  //After this, id is 1
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){
        id = 1;
    }
}); //Now id is 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after the listener finishes, the id goes to 0", where & how are you checking this?

Comment: The `"id"` is the same as the `fied id`?

Comment: @Lewis McGeary when the listener is called, the id is set to 1, but then it goes back to 0 when it finishes. I am using the android debug to see the value of the id and logging the values.

Comment: @LewisMcGeary oops didn't tag you right in the comment above

Comment: @AlexM. The id is an int

Comment: @ConnorT that isn't really precise enough to explain what *you* mean by "finishes" in this case(eg. in the code above you could say the listener is never finished, it continues listening). To help people answer I'd suggest editing your question to add more code and pointing out where exactly in the code the value is different than you would expect.

Comment: @LewisMcGeary sorry it's a single value event listener I edited it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things come to mind from this question, one about Firebase listeners and the second about removing excess code.

A fundamental thing about Firebase listeners is that they are *asynchronous*, meaning your code does not wait for the result before executing the next line. So look at the comments in this skeleton code:

```
userRef.child("id").
addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        // code here does not get executed straight away,
        // it gets executed whenever data is received back from the remote database
    }

    @Override public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){

    }
});
// if you have a line of code here immediately after adding the listener
// the onDataChange code *won't have run*. You go straight to these lines
// of code, the onDataChange method will run whenever it's ready.
```

So this means that if you want to do something with the data you are getting in `onDataChange` you should put that code inside the `onDataChange` method (or some other method called from there or in some other way running that code *after* the data has been delivered back).

Regarding the second part, a slightly more *Firebasey* way of checking for existence of an int and getting the value would be:

```
@Override public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        id = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
    } else {
        id = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will check if this works next time I can. I am on vacation right now.

Comment: Great, have fun 

Comment: @LewisMcGeary Does `onDataChange(){...}` return data from the remote database, for the first time without any change to the data stored remotely? Could you please clarify? [My Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874244/valueeventlistener-not-working-as-expected) is related to this. Thanks

Comment: @user3314337 yes it will return the first time with whatever is there (and to avoid confusion for anyone reading, because this question is about `SingleValueEventListeners` it will ONLY run the first time and won't update again with any changes). I'll check your question

Answer (score 0):

you need to set id = 1 into firebase database using setValue(), try below line of code it might help you

```
   userRef.child("id").

  addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    try {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        id = Integer.parseInt(value);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
         // if id=0 then set id=1 using setvalue()
        // this will set value of Id =1 in firebase database 
             id=1;                 
        userRef.child("id").setValue(id);
        log.d(LOG_TAG, e.printStackTrace());
    }
}

@Override public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){
            id=1;
          userRef.child("id").setValue(id);
   }
});
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do , i think yo want to store id to 1 if there is no value for id in database ? right

Comment: I am already setting the id in the database another time, then checking if it not null. Thanks anyway, but I don't think this is the solution

Comment: What you want is if id is null then set to 1,  i think you must give it a try.  If id is null first it will set to 1 and as soon as this setValue() executes  listners will get to know that there is a change in id and your piece of code will executes and this time dataSnaphot will not throw null pointer  exception

Answer (score 0):

I had kinda the same problem of getting an object out of FireBase Realtime Database, 
and as @Lewis McGeary wrote, I Just made my program Wait until all the data gets retrived from the Database

Here's my sample code:

```
BarReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(myUID);
ValueEventListener UserChangeListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        me = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDataSet.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};
BarReference.addValueEventListener(UserChangeListener);
while (me == null){
   Log.w(TAG, "Waiting For The Data to Download");
   progresBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   return;
}
```

Hope that Helps! `(^_^)`

Answer (score 0):

Using "addValueEventListener" instead of "addListenerForSingleValueEvent" worked for me.

```
ValueEventListener locListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                 //do stuff here
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        };
        db.addValueEventListener(locListener);
```