# ValueEventListener not Working as expected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display the data stored in Firebase, in AutoCompleteTextView's Dropdown. For this purpose, I am using the **ValueEventListener**. According to the documentation of **ValueEventListener**,

> You can use the onDataChange() method to read a static snapshot of the
>   contents at a given path, as they existed at the time of the event.
>   This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again
>   every time the data, including children, changes.

Unfortunately, in my case **onDataChange()** is triggered only when data the is changed(that is, when new data is added). This means the AutoCompleteTextView doesn't display the dropdown without any change to the data in Firebase. What I want, is for the **onDataChange()** to trigger for the first time when the Listener is called and every time the data changes. I would like to know where I am going wrong. The following code appears inside **onCreateView** of Fragment

```
daTags.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Basically, this says "For each DataSnapshot *Data* in dataSnapshot, do what's inside the method.
            for (DataSnapshot tagNameSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Get the suggestion by childing the key of the string you want to get.
                String ValueTagName = tagNameSnapshot.child(getResources().getString(R.string.Child_AppData_Tags_TagName)).getValue(String.class);
                //Add ValueTagName (Value pulled from Firebase for the above Key) to TagList
                //Is better to use a List, because you don't know the size of the iterator returned by dataSnapshot.getChildren() to initialize the array
                tagList.add(ValueTagName);

                //Initialize AutoCompleteTextView and define Adapter
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapterAutoComplete = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tagList);
                actv_tagName.setAdapter(adapterAutoComplete);

                //Get TagsCount using dataSnapshot and display TagsCount in TextView
                TagsCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + "";
                tv_tagsCount.setText(TagsCount);
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: The `onDataChange()` method does indeed run once for the initial data and then again with any changes as described. I'd guess the problem is to do with the AutoCompleteTextView and Adapter though I don't have time to test it out. Try putting a Log message or something in onDataChange to confirm whether the onDataChange is running or not.

Comment: `onDataChange(){}` isn't providing the initial data. However, after changing the existing data(adding a new data) in the remote database, the `onDataChange(){}` is working as expected (as mentioned in the question above). I would like to know what is causing the `onDataChange(){}` to not return the initial data.

Comment: How have you verified onDataChange is not being triggered the first time?

Comment: I didn't use the Log for verification. For the `AutoCompleteTextView`, I have the `threshold` set to 2 letters. For initial data, the `AutoCompleteTextView` doesn't display a dropdown. Also, the `TagCount` displays 0 for the initial data. But after adding a new data to the remote database, the AutoCompleteTextView displays a drop-down if it finds a match. Likewise, the TagCount returns the number of Tags stored in the remote database.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood the problem. To make it work, I will have to move the following lines of code outside the *For loop*

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterAutoComplete = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tagList);
actv_tagName.setAdapter(adapterAutoComplete);
```

When inside the For loop, the adapter gets updated for every loop. Placing the above code outside *For loop*, overcomes the issue.